# What's the minimum permissions I can give to someone on AppStore Connect for TestFlight testing?

Tags: permissions, app-store-connect

I want to distribute an app through TestFlight to one of my internal testers. They don't need any permissions besides downloading via TestFlight.

When I create their account on Users and Roles, I'm presented with this interface:

[image]

Which of those 8 roles will provide the minimum privileges but enough to download via TestFlight?

Answer (score 8):

```
+------------------+--------------------+-------------------------+
|       Role       | App Features count | Provider Features count |
+------------------+--------------------+-------------------------+
| Admin            |                 16 |                       6 |
| App Manager      |                 14 |                       3 |
| Marketer         |                  9 |                       0 |
| Developer        |                  8 |                       0 |
| Finance          |                  2 |                       3 |
| Sales            |                  2 |                       0 |
| Customer Support |                  1 |                       0 |
+------------------+--------------------+-------------------------+
```

So your best bet is either Sales or Customer Support, depending on which permissions you would like to give the user:

Sales:

- View App Analytics
- View Sales and Trends (Sales Only)

Customer Support:

- Reply to and Edit Responses to Customer Reviews

Comment: Apple has updated the permissions. It would be useful to everyone if you update your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can find here the roles determined: https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/

For the minimum permissions that are still can test the beta builds via Testflight, I think `Customer Support` is the appropriate role.

Comment: It is not appropriate. They should introduce a role without any permissions but using a specific TestFlight build. The customer support role gives way to much authorization for internal testers.

Comment: This is Apple being Apple. Given the limited options Customer Support is probably the best for now. But I agree that there should be a better role.